# Wait until command queue done all enqueued jobs

Tags: cross-platform, opencl

I have an algorithm that schedules subtasks between multiple devices to solve main_task. It enqueues kernel to all command queues and attaches an event with a callback.
In this callback I check whether my main_task is done and if it's not, I enqueue one more subtask. Otherwise I set shared variable `is_main_task_done` to `true` to notify other command queues that they should stop enqueueing subtasks.

Meanwhile I have to somehow prevent host's main thread from exit until `is_main_task_done` is set to `true`. Is there a cross platform solution? I've found only spinlock solution in AMD's guide so far:

```
while (!is_main_task_done)
 sleep(0)
```

But it appears to work in Windows only.

Comment: you set is_task_done=true if your task is not done. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry. I've updated terminology. Basically it's a kind of for-loop with different ranges on different threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to use semaphores here. Initialize the semaphore with the number of tasks you want to have running, and it will be ensured that only this number runs.

Comment: I meant the number of parallel tasks (perhaps it's just 1 at a time).

Comment: How does this differ from spinlock?

Comment: it's blocking, no busy waiting. The kernel will wake up the next task that can do work as soon as one task is done (so very efficient).

Comment: First you should learn about the concept. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29  http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/semaphore.c You can implement using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads there is a windows version for it. If everything is in one program, OpenMP would be an easy solution.

Comment: I've studied [semaphore.c](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/semaphore.c) and found that it's essentially a spin lock with sleep inside

Comment: no, the sleep happens in the kernel in this example (pthread_mutex_[un]lock) -- perhaps it's better if you look at http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_init. The process/thread is inactive while it waits. You don't waste cycles unlike busy waiting. Not sure how you can do mutex/semaphores best on Windows.

Comment: There is a lightweight mutex library, so I can implement a semaphore on top of it. But what would be the cross platform sleep?